# How to properly calculate the run time of a battery using a power converter?

Tags: power, inverter, watts, time

I want to buy a 12v 100ah lithium battery to power a 750 watts power converter that provides 120V.

I would like to know how many hours of energy will I have with this information. I tried some online calculators, but it's not clear if I'm doing it right.

Why?

Well, the 750 watts is related to the 120V part of the power converter, so I don't know how to calculate on the 12V part of the battery.

Comment: Do you have the discharge curves for the battery? And the undervoltage lockout point for the inverter?  With those two things you can get a realistic estimate for the run time of the inverter with a given inverter input power.  (Input power=output power/efficiency.)

Comment: What is the load on the inverter? A 750W inverter can supply a MAXIMUM of 750W. The actual amount depends on the load. The power input to the inverter at 12V will be a few percent more than the output because of inefficiencies.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/LiFePO4-Battery-Perfect-Applications-Warranty/dp/B084DB36KW/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=W394OQSRY3K0&keywords=100%2Bah%2Blifepo4%2Bbattery%2B12v&qid=1706139583&sprefix=100%2Bah%2Caps%2C128&sr=8-2-spons&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.c3015c4a-46bb-44b9-81a4-dc28e6d374b3&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1

Comment: That's the battery I have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a 12 volt 100Ah battery has an equivalent watt-hour rating of 12 x 100 i.e. 1200 watt-hours (Wh). So, if your load needs 750 watts then the battery will typically be able to supply that power for 1 hour and 36 minutes.

However, there is not much info about the battery and, it may droop its terminal voltage both under load and, over time so, I wouldn't bet on getting anything more than 1 hour from the battery.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/LiFePO4-Battery-Perfect-Applications-Warranty/dp/B084DB36KW/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=W394OQSRY3K0&keywords=100%2Bah%2Blifepo4%2Bbattery%2B12v&qid=1706139583&sprefix=100%2Bah%2Caps%2C128&sr=8-2-spons&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.c3015c4a-46bb-44b9-81a4-dc28e6d374b3&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1

Comment: That's the battery I have in mind.

Comment: @RobertodeNobrega I'm unsure how this battery information is relevant. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.